# Grabbing nodes that aren't descendants of other nodes, excluding the current context

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, nodes

So, I have no idea how to really word this question. I want to have a list of nodes, and only select the one node, but not the nested node. For example:

```
<root>
    <my_element>
        <my_element>
            Some Text
        </my_element>
    </my_element>
</root>
```

I know I can already do some of what I want by using this xpath:

```
Context: /
xPath: descendant::my_element[not(ancestor::my_element)]
```

Which would return this result set:

```
<root>
    [<my_element>]
        <my_element>
            Some Text
        </my_element>
    [</my_element>]
</root>
```

That's the expected behaviour of what I want. But I want to be able to change the context to:

```
/my_element
```

And get this result set:

```
<root>
    <my_element>
        [<my_element>]
            Some Text
        [</my_element>]
    </my_element>
</root>
```

I've tried my best at looking at xPath documents and I haven't come up with much of anything. Perchance someone on here could provide some insight?

Thanks!

- edit -
  I want to be able to select a my_element descendant which isn't an ancestor of my_element excluding the context node.
- edit again -
  To further explain.

I want to have an xpath query that selects nodes of `my_element` so long as the node  isn't a child of `my_element`. But, if the xpath context is set to a `my_element` node, then I don't want that node to count in the expression. So the xpath would then match the next `my_element` node, even though it is actually a child of `my_element`.

- edit again -

Here are some more examples.

```
<root>
    <a>
        <a>
            <b>
                <a>
                    Hello!
                </a>
            </b>
            <a>
                <b>
                    Hello Again
                    <a>
                        Sub
                    </a>
                </b>
            </a>
        </a>
    </a>
</root>

Context: /root/
Desire: Want to grab all A nodes, so long as they aren't a descendant of A

Result:
<root> == Context
    [<a>]
        <a>
            <b>
                <a>
                    Hello!
                </a>
            </b>
            <a>
                <b>
                    Hello Again
                    <a>
                        Sub
                    </a>
                </b>
            </a>
        </a>
    [</a>]
</root>

Context: /root/a/
Desire: Want to grab all A nodes, so long as they aren't a descendant of A, not including the context /root/a/

Result:
<root>
    <a> == Context
        [<a>]
            <b>
                <a>
                    Hello!
                </a>
            </b>
            <a>
                <b>
                    Hello Again
                    <a>
                        Sub
                    </a>
                </b>
            </a>
        [</a>]
    </a>
</root>

Context: /root/a/a/
Desire: Want to grab all A nodes, so long as they aren't a descendant of A, not including the context /root/a/a/

Result:
<root>
    <a>
        <a> == Context
            <b>
                [<a>]
                    Hello!
                [</a>]
            </b>
            [<a>]
                <b>
                    Hello Again
                    <a>
                        Sub
                    </a>
                </b>
            [</a>]
        </a>
    </a>
</root>

Context: /root/a/a/a/
Desire: Want to grab all A nodes, so long as they aren't a descendant of A, not including the context /root/a/a/a/

Result:
<root>
    <a>
        <a>
            <b>
                <a>
                    Hello!
                </a>
            </b>
            <a> == Context
                <b>
                    Hello Again
                    [<a>]
                        Sub
                    [</a>]
                </b>
            </a>
        </a>
    </a>
</root>
```

I hope this makes my desires clearer. Thank you everyone who is trying!

Comment: @Kyle: Aren't those just the `my_element` children? Unless you want a `my_element` descendant wich doesn't have a `my_element` ancestor excluding context node and its ancestor.

Comment: Your latter is correct. I want to be able to select a my_element descendant which isn't an ancestor of my_element excluding the context node.

Comment: @Kyle: I think you can't in XPath 1.0 because the need to reference the context node.

Comment: @Alejandro: Would it be possible if I put the context inside of the xpath and checked against it there? IE: /my_element/descendant::my_element[not(ancestor::my_element)]

Comment: @Kyle: No. The only expression I could come up with is `./descendant::my_element[1]` wich selects first decendant (it won't have a `my_element` ancestor then) but it wouldn't select the rest of `my_element` in other context node children branch.

Comment: @Alejandro: Aye. Thanks for taking a look, though.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XPath one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//my_element[not(.//my_element)]
```

This selects all elements named `my_element` that don't have any `my_element` descendents.

Comment: This doesn't selects outer most `my_element` with `root` as context node.

Comment: @Alejandro: Sorry, could you explain? The OP wants: "I want to be able to select a my_element descendant which isn't an ancestor of my_element excluding the context node" -- and this is what the XPath expression in my answer selects. ???

Comment: Not quite. See, that would work, except I want to disclude the context node from the test, which could by my_element. Actually, reading thing your again, you're completely wrong with what I wanted. No problem. see this xpath: descendant::my_element[not(ancestor::my_element)]. This works great. Except for when the xpath context is set to a my_element, in which case, I don't want the xpath expression to care about the parent (context node). So something like this would work, if it were actual valid xpath: descendant::my_element[not(ancestor::my_element) except context]

Comment: @Kyle: I am willing to help. Here the main problem is that you haven't until now explained the problem in such a way that people would understand it (I definitely don't -- what "disclude" means?). Please, edit your question and explain well. @Alejandro, in case you understand the question, please, edit it so that more people, including me, could understand it. It seems that Dr. Kay is having the same difficulty.

Comment: @Kyle: A hint. Provide a simple example. Don't use names such as `my_element` -- they are confusing. Use `A`, `B`, `C`. In the example define which is the initial context node. Then enumerate the nodes that must be selected. Finally, explain what requirements should the selection fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be falling into a common trap. The XPath expression /root/my_element, on your data, will select only one element - the outermost my_element node. But that node is still attached to its parents, siblings, and children. When you display the result of the selection, the node will often be displayed together with its children (indeed, all descendants) - not because the XPath selected the children, but because that's a friendly way to display the single node that was selected.

On the other hand, I've read the question again, and I might be wrong - I guessed that from the peculiar notation you were using to show the results of your XPath expression.

The expression /my_element will select my_element only if its parent is the document node at the root of the tree, which will never be the case with your input, whatever your context node. Of course, you can copy the subtree rooted at my_element into a new document, in which case this expression will work.

Comment: The OP is asking for an XPath 1.0 equivalent expression to this XPath 2.0 expression `.//my_element except .//my_element//my_element`